# How to set Colour of a Provinces using AMCharts 4 Maps

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to display a map of Canada with selected provinces a different colour than the rest. I can make this work no problem if I want to display a map of the world with selected countries a different colour. But the same code does not work for provinces.

Here is my JavaScript:

```js
// Create map instance
var chart = am4core.create("map", am4maps.MapChart);

// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_canadaLow;

// Set projection
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

// Create map polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

// Make map load polygon (like country names) data from GeoJSON
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

// Configure series
var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#74B266");

// Create hover state and set alternative fill color
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");

// Add some data
polygonSeries.data = [{
  "id": "ON",
  "name": "Ontario",
  "value": 100,
  "fill": am4core.color("#F05C5C")
}, {
  "id": "QC",
  "name": "Quebec",
  "value": 50,
  "fill": am4core.color("#5C5CFF")
}];

// Bind "fill" property to "fill" key in data
polygonTemplate.propertyFields.fill = "fill";
```

All provinces appear the same colour:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well, the only issue is that you don't use the right IDs.

I got it working by using "CA-ON" for Ontario & "CA-QC" for Quebec.